# LLVM comparing between a pointer and a constant

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm trying to build llvm IR code manually (injecting a function). I'm having issues with building a compare instruction:

```
    auto *var0 = Builder->CreateLoad(StrPtr);
    var0->getType()->dump(); // i8 addrspace(8)*
    Builder->getInt8(0)->getType()->dump(); // i8
    auto *cmp5 = Builder->CreateICmpEQ(var0, Builder->getInt8(0));
```

I can't compare between var0 and Builder->getInt8(0) as the dump indicates they have different types. 
Specifically I get this error during runtime:

```
opt: /llvm/include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h:1174: void
llvm::ICmpInst::AssertOK(): Assertion `getOperand(0)->getType() == 
getOperand(1)->getType() && "Both operands to ICmp instruction are not of 
the same type!"' failed.
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IR is an assembly language — low level. There is no automatic casting in assembly languages (unless I want to digress and go into detail) so you really cannot compare a 32- or 64-bit pointer with an 8-bit integer. If you want to cast you have to implement it yourself, according to the rules of your source language.

In this case, what you what is probably a [pointer to int cast](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CastInst.html#aa14a4fadff2413072ac706ffee0b3210) and either a [sign extension](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CastInst.html#a92a5a74a73a8ec83f946fe3e89e8f967) or a [zero extension](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1CastInst.html#a1466706200fe33c0f3488c3dd6a1eef0), so both sides of the comparison are integers and have the same bit width. Most likely a zero extension, but I mention both to emphasise that you have to think about these things.

Comment: This isn't compiled from a source language. This is a pass plugin where I inject my own function which I build from IR assembly. I know this can be done without a CastInst since I compiled a similar C-version of this function I'm injecting which uses just LoadInst followed up by a ICmpEq. I will add that code here later today.

Comment: Of course it can be done without a castinst. You could use matching types to begun with, or cast using a constantexpr instead of an instruction, if either/both exprs are constant.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is to build this IR code:

```
%0 = load i8, i8* %String, align 1, !tbaa !2
%cmp5 = icmp eq i8 %0, 0
```
I'm don't know how to build this with IRBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured how to do what arnt said, here's the code:

```
auto *var0 = Builder->CreateLoad(StrPtr);
auto *cmp5 = Builder->CreateICmpEQ(var0, Constant::getNullValue(Type::getInt8PtrTy(Ctx, 8)));
```

getNullValue seeds my new constant with a 0 which is just what I needed.